# How to clean a list for a specific string and return the cleaned list or NONE

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I need to write a function to answer these specifications:

`clean_list( [],s1] = NONE`

`clean_list( xs, "") = NONE`

`clean_list ([s1, s1, s1, s1], s1) = NONE`

`clean_list([s1, s2, s3, s2, s1], s3) = [s1, s2, s2, s1]`

where `s1`, `s2`, `s3` are some strings and `xs` a list of strings.

I was able to do it using the two helper functions `is_into(xs: string list, s1: string) -> bool` and `remove(xs: string list, s1: string) -> string list` but it seems ugly to recurse twice through the list.

```
clean_list(xs: string list, s1: string) =
    case (xs, s1) of
         ( [], _ ) => NONE
        |( _, "" ) => NONE
        |( _, _) => if is_into(xs, s1)
                    then remove(xs, s1)
                    else NONE
```

Is there a way to do it without recursing in the list twice (once in `is_into` and once in `remove`)?

Note: None of builtin functions are to be used.

Sorry i forgot an **important case** in the specifications

```
clean_list ([s1, s2, s3, s4], s10] = NONE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily go through the list once, element by element and removing all that matches the given string, returning `SOME lst` at the end, where `lst` is the resulting list

```
fun clean_list ([], _ ) = NONE
  | clean_list (_, "") = NONE
  | clean_list (xs, str) =
    let
      fun clean_list' [] = []
        | clean_list' (x::xs) =
          if x = str then
            clean_list' xs
          else
            x :: clean_list' xs
    in
      SOME (clean_list' xs)
    end
```

**Update**

I noticed that the above code actually doesn't handle the case: `clean_list ([s1, s1, s1, s1], s1) = NONE`. However this is an easy fix.

I can see that given your new updated specification, that if the element is not in the list in the first place, then `NONE` should be returned. This is the same as saying, if no elements was removed while going through all the elements, then return `NONE`.

Hopefully you can see that this can be implemented by added an extra Boolean argument to the helper function, initially setting it to false, and then passing along its value in each recursive call, except in the case where an element is removed, here it can always be set to true.

This can then be used to determine weather to return the `SOME lst`, where `lst` is the resulting list, or `NONE` if no elements was removed.

Given these two things, that needs to be fixed, it would probably bee a good idea to have the helper function built up its result in an accumulating argument, instead. This way you have full control and can easily return `NONE` when the accumulating list is empty at the end.

Comment: i forgot an **important case** in the specifications

    clean_list ([s1, s2, s3, s4], s10] = NONE

Comment: @sonia, you should easily be able to extend the provided solution to handle this. Btw I have spottet that this (`clean_list ([s1, s1, s1, s1], s1) = NONE`) case isn't handled correctly either.  
If not, then you should rephrase/edit your question to reflect what it is that you are having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

Your `clean_list` function doesn't typecheck since some branches have type `'a option` and others have type `'b list`.

Assuming you would like to return `'b list`, `NONE` should be replaced by `[]`. You can use pattern matching recursively on `clean_list` to avoid the need of auxiliary functions:

```
fun clean_list(xs: string list, s1: string) =
    case (xs, s1) of
      ([], _) => []
    | (_, "") => []
    | (x::xs', _) => if x = s1 
                     then clean_list(xs', s1)
                     else x::clean_list(xs', s1)
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot an **important case** in the specifications

    clean_list ([s1, s2, s3, s4], s10] = NONE